# Android lock screen Chromecast buttons

Tags: android, chromecast

I’m trying to add the FWD and REW buttons to the Android lock screen for my Chromecast sender app but it doesn’t want to show.

Answer (score 3):

The Android team has confirmed that the FWD and REW buttons are not supported on the lock screen. The Cast UX requirements only specify that the Play/Pause button is required for the lock screen. You can use the Next and Prev buttons but you won't be able to customize the standard icons used for those actions.